# Updating objects in an Ember many to many relationship

Tags: ember.js, many-to-many, ember-data

I have an app which allows me to create a message which can be sent to N number of social networks, modeled as follows:

```
Social.Account = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr("string"),
    messages: DS.hasMany("Social.Message")
});

Social.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr("string"),
    account: DS.belongsTo("Social.Account")
});
```

My code for creating a record looks like this:

```
saveMessage: function(){
    var account = Social.Account.find(this.get("id")),
        msg = Social.store.createRecord(
                  Social.Message,
                  {
                      text: postingWindow.get('text'),
                      account: account,
                  }
              );
    account.get("messages").addObject(msg);
    Social.store.commit();
}
```

With the form data looking like this:

```
text:testing one three five seven
message_key:
tags:
user_id:
created:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 21:39:14 GMT
scheduled_at:2013-06-20T03:00:00.000Z
is_editing:false
status:C
account:56
```

That part works excellent. Now we're working on scheduling future messages, which offers the user the chance to edit them after they've been saved, but before they've been sent. On the surface my implementation seems to work properly, but I noticed that Ember was not sending the account information along with the post, which meant that when my server code ran, the message was being orphaned in the database. Here's the update code:

```
sendNow: function(message){
    var account = Social.Account.find( this.get('controllers.account.id') );
    message.setProperties({
        scheduled_at: '',
        accounts: [account]
        // I've also tried accounts: this.get('controllers.account.id')
    });
    Social.store.commit();
}
```

And the corresponding form data:

```
text:testing one three five seven
message_key:
tags:
user_id:17
created:Wed, 19 Jun 2013 21:39:14 GMT
scheduled_at:
is_editing:false
```

No matter what I do, Ember isn't sending the account data to the server. Is there a more appropriate way to update a record and cause it to be saved properly?

Comment: So it looks like the problem was our server code initially. We were sending `accounts`, but the Ember model was `account`. Until now it wasn't a problem because Messages were always pulled in via sideload within the Accounts call. So we're good now. Thank you to everyone who took a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
message.get('accounts').pushObject(account')
```

Comment: Hrm. That's between the setProperties and Social.store.commit() calls?

Comment: Yes.. but I wouldn't try to set the accounts value through the setProperties call

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. This: `message.get('accounts')` returns undefined, while this: `message.get('account')` returns null. So when I try to use `pushObject` I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the var account is being set?  Seems like you are inconsistent with the get statements:

`var account = Social.Account.find(this.get("id"))` ,  <- double quotes

`var account = Social.Account.find(this.get('controllers.account.id'));` <- single quotes and different object structure?

Also, did you try:
`message.set('accounts', account);`